# What is causing these Gatling errors?

Tags: openssl, keycloak, keystore, gatling

Gatling is erroring saying openssl isnt available and yet gatling.conf has the keystore.server configured and the java service using the same keystore.

Any ideas why gatling would fail?

mvn gatling:test -DkeycloakUrl="https://10.134.17.232:8443" -DkeycloakRealm=LOAD -Dduration=10  -DconcurrentUsers=10 -DkeycloakClients=10 -DkeycloakUsers=10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, don't use an outdated version of Gatling:

- current version of Gatling is 3.9.3
- current version of gatling-maven-plugin is 4.3.1

Once you've properly upgraded, if you still face this issue, please provide a [proper reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).